# Two form fields into one entity value

Tags: symfony

How its possible to join two separated fields (must be separated) in one form (date and time for example) to one entity propery datetime for persisting after form post ?

What is better way ? Data Transofmers ? Form events ? Form Model ? Manual setting all entity properties before persist ?

Entity:

```
<?php namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="event")
 */
class EventEntity
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $datetime;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // ...

    public function getDateTime()
    {
        return $this->datetime;
    }

    public function setDateTime(\DateTime $datetime)
    {
        $this->datetime = $datetime;
    }

}
```

FormType:

```
<?php namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class EventType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('date', 'date', [
                    'required' => true,
                    'widget'   => 'single_text',
                    'format'   => 'dd.MM.yyyy'
                ]
            )
            ->add('time', 'time', [
                    'required' => false,
                    'widget'   => 'single_text'
                ]
            );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\EventEntity' //Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Model\EventModel ?
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'event';
    }

}
```

Comment: DataTransformers are made for that. Symfony use them to convert a 3 field date form (Y/m/d) into one DateTime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

héhé, that's a good question.

I would choose the easiest, most generic, reusable solution.
I wouldn't implement methods on my model just for sake of form mapping, but if it makes sense, why not simply using the model api ?

```php
<?php

class EventEntity
{
// assume $this->datetime is initialized and instance of DateTime

public function setDate(\DateTime $date)
{
    // i don't know if this works!
    $this->datetime->add($this->datetime->diff($date));
}


public function setTime(\DateTime $date)
{
    $this->datetime->add($this->datetime->diff($date));
}
}
```

Comment: maybe like this 

`public function __construct() { $this->datetime = new \DateTime(); }

public function setTime(\DateTime $datetime) { $this->datetime->setTime($datetime->format('H'), $datetime->format('i')); }

public function setDate(\DateTime $datetime) { $this->datetime->setDate($datetime->format('Y'), $datetime->format('m'), $datetime->format('d')); }`

Comment: I accept Floarian answer because its more universal. But Pazis answer is very good for date/time.

Answer (score 7):

If you set the date and time widget seperately in the datetime type, then they get seperately rendered, but validated as one field.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('datetime', 'datetime', array(
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
        ));
}
```

Comment: its possible to set time as not required ?

Comment: the required in the form builder regards only to the HTML5 required attribute. In validation the `NotBlank` is neccesary to validate if a field is really filled out. The requirements are a little bit tricky.

Comment: yes i know its only HTML5 but i need it.. pity :/ but its also can be "hacked" adding in twig `{ 'attr':{'required':'required'}, 'label_attr':{'class':'required'} }`

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using Pazis solution, since this is the most simple one. But that would also be a perfect job for a DataTransformer:

```
class MyDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
  public function transform($value)
  {
    if (null === $value)
      return;

    if ($value instanceof \DateTime)
      return array(
        'date' => $value->format('d.m.Y'),
        'time' => $value->format('H:i:s')
      );

    return null;
  }

  public function reverseTransform($value)
  {
    if (null === $value)
      return null;

    if (is_array($value) && array_key_exists('date', $value) && array_key_exists('time', $value))
      return new \DateTime($value['date'] . ' ' . $value['time']);

    return null; 
  }
}
```

This has the drawback, that you'd need to map every single value in your entity with this transformer, what - for sure - you don't want to. But with small form-tricks, this can be avoided. Therefore you add a subform to your form, which includes a date and a time field and the added Transformer. You'll need to map ("property_path"-option) your DateTime object to this subform or just name it "correctly", so the form framework can map it by name.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add(
        $builder->create('datetime', 'form')
                ->add('date', 'date', $optionsForDate)
                ->add('time', 'time', $optionsForTime)
                ->addViewTransformer(new MyDataTransformer())
    );
}
```

The code may not be perfectly running, but i hope the idea behind splitting one entity property into two (or more) form fields is clear.

Comment: Great solution, saved me another question. Thanks!